# servicestack VueJS Compile failure

Tags: typescript, vue.js, servicestack, dotnet-tool

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvnb3.png)

After installing Vuejs in the servicestack then run the project it shows error like this.kindly give a solutions

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven’t run ‘npm install’ in your AppHost project. You can do this via Visual Studio by right clicking of ‘package.json’ and selecting “Restore Packages” or by running the command as normal using the windows command prompt.

The best template to use for a Vue Single Page Application (SPA) and ServiceStack is the one from the ServiceStack `x` tool.

Installing the `x` tool can be done using the command

```
dotnet tool install -g x
```

Once installed, you can create a new Vue SPA project but using the command

```
x new vue-spa ExampleApp
```

Where `ExampleApp` is the name you give your application.

Once installed, using a command prompt, navigate into the new project folder and the AppHost to run the `npm install` command.

```
cd ExampleApp
cd ExampleApp
npm install
```

More details about the template are [available in the ServiceStack docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-vue), and a [walk through video tutorial](https://youtu.be/4HphWPrKwb0) using the template is available on the ServiceStack YouTube channel.

Comment: Still I'm facing the same error. Please help how to install vuejs spa in the servicestack..

Comment: If you update your answer with more details about how you got to the state of problems you are having, myself and others will have a better chance to be able to help. For now, I've updated my answer to provide a step by step to get VueJS + ServiceStack template working as well as linking to additional resources, including a full video tutorial, walking through those steps.